# Using properties defined in the Options constructor within custom methods in mootools

Tags: javascript, raphael, mootools

I'm starting with the Mootools framework. Since I want the code to be reusable, I'm trying to do it with classes.

In the code shown below, the intention is to draw a Map using Raphael framework for SVG. The code is working fine, but I'm having problems with the properties that are inside the `Options` object.

```
var Map = new Class({

Implements : [ Options ],

pathsArr: {},

Options: {
    canvas: {
        container: 'map',
        cheight: 500,
        cwidth: 900,
    },
    attributes: {
        fill: '#006699',
        stroke: '#3899E6',
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'stroke-linejoin': 'round'
    }   
},

initialize: function (pathsArr, options){
    this.setOptions(Options);
    this.pathsArr = paths;
    console.log(this.pathsArr);
},

setCanvas: function(){
    console.log(this.Options.canvas);
    R = Raphael(this.Options.canvas.container, this.Options.canvas.cwidth, this.Options.canvas.cheight);
    return R;
},

drawPaths: function(){
    console.log(this.Options.attributes);
    for (var country in this.pathsArr){
        var shape = R.path(this.pathsArr[country].path);
        var attri = this.Options.attributes;
        console.log(attri);
        
    }
}
```

});

Ok, like you can see I'm using `console.log` to understand how things are happening here. And when I check the attributes in the line

```
console.log(this.Options.attributes);
```

I get this in the Google Chrome console

[image]

When I think I need something like what happend when I check the `pathsArr` wich is outside the `Options` object.

[image]

And where I need the attributes property nothing happens. Like in these two lines.

```
var attri = this.Options.attributes;
shape.attr(attri);
```

And I don't understand why if I do this, it gets the correct result.

```
console.log(this.Options.attributes.fill);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive. Use `setOptions(options)` and `this.options` instead of `Options`. The capital `O` is there only when a reference is made to the `Options` mutator, as in the `Implements: [Options]` instruction.

Currently, your `Options` member can not be set by the `setOptions` call, since it is looking for `this.options`.

You're only using `this.Options`, that is your default options, that are never updated. And `this.options` is set to the  `Options` mutator, as you instruct when writing `this.setOptions(Options)`.

*EDIT:*

Also, in the following code:

```
initialize: function (pathsArr, options){
    this.setOptions(Options);
    this.pathsArr = paths;  // <----- `paths` is undefined
```

Comment: Wow, that was a complete answer! Grammar correction + an answer to the problem. Thank you so much! I'm learning english and JavaScript programming at the same time!